# Trouble selecting parent id of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select class of different id.

I got the id and alert it but unable to get parent id. Please help me!

THANKS

Here is what i have been trying:

**HTML**

```
<div id="inp1" class="col-md-12">

  <button id="1p" class="cr1 btn btn-default col-md-3" type="button">Go!</button>
  <input type="text" required value="input 1" name="opt1_1" class="btn btn-default col-md-9">

</div>
```

```
  <button id="2p" class="cr1 btn btn-default col-md-3" type="button">Go!</button>
   <input type="text" required value="input 2" name="opt1_2" class="btn btn-default col-md-9">
</div>



       jQuery
     $('.cr1').click(function(){
     var cr= $(this).attr("id");
      var getpar= cr.parent().attr('id');
         alert(getpar);
        });
```

Comment: `var getpar = $(this).parent().attr('id')` - the "cr" variable just has the button's "id" in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cr is a string containing the button's id, it is not an element

you should do

```
$(this).parent().attr('id');
```

see:http://jsfiddle.net/5hBrH/

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zm556/)

```
 $('.cr1').click(function(){
 var $this = $(this); //<-- changed
 var cr= $(this).attr("id");
  var getpar= $this.parent().attr('id');//<-- changed
     alert(getpar);
    });
```